# Django : stop access to my web app from being accessed on port 8000 and access only using the IP

Tags: python, django, apache, http, webserver

I have deployed my Django web app on a digital ocean droplet. The python server is running on port 8000.

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

I have configured apache web server to serve the requests.

/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /etc/myproject

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        #Serving static files
        Alias /static/ /etc/myproject/static/
        <Directory /etc/myproject/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /etc/myproject/myproject>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>
        WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-path=/etc/myproject python-home=/etc/myprojectenv
        WSGIProcessGroup myproject
        WSGIScriptAlias / /etc/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

Now when I am accessing my web app using the IP address X.X.X.X, I am able to see my app, however the app is also accessible on port 8000, X.X.X.X:8000.

I want to prevent my app from being accessed on any other port except being accessed ousing IP. How can I do that?

Comment: Stop the `runserver` process.

Comment: but if I do that, how will my python server be able to serve requests?

Comment: Are you using multiple servers or single server ?

Comment: just this, single server

Comment: It will be served by mod_wsgi in Apache.

Comment: I was confused, I thought its important to run django server as well for my website to be accessible by apache web server. Although when I shut down python server I was still able to access my webapp, and I thought it must be due to apache caching my webpage and I did not realize that its the mod_wsgi which runs in the background to serve requests. that was all misconception, thanks for clearing my doubts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I was missing a point here that I don't need to run Django server as well when I have configured Apache web server to serve my requests. All request are served by the mod_wsgi Apache module. The mod_wsgi package provides an Apache module that implements a WSGI compliant interface for hosting Python based web applications on top of the Apache web server.